# Select multiple rows from table using checkboxes

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, checkbox

I'm trying to use checkboxes for multiple sql query with SELECT.

I have 3 tables, one table for *groups* one for *users* and one to connect the user to different groups called *groupreluser*. Based on what groups are checked, I want it to print out the phonenumber of each user that are a member of those groups.

The checkboxes are created based on the content of the table *groups*

```
<form method="post">
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM groups WHERE groupname LIKE '%minor%'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if($result->num_rows > 0){

            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

                    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="checked[]" value="'.$row['group_id'].'">'
                    . $row['groupname'] . '</br>';

            }

    }
?>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Code with the sql query to get the phonenumbers.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $check = $_POST['checked'];

    if(!empty($check)){


            foreach($check as $sel){
                    $sel = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $sel);


                    $sql = "

                            SELECT
                                    groups.group_id,
                                    groups.groupname,
                                    groupreluser.user_id,
                                    groupreluser.group_id,
                                    users.user_id,
                                    users.name,
                                    users.phone
                            FROM
                                    groupreluser
                            JOIN
                                    groups
                            ON
                                    groups.group_id = groupreluser.group_id
                            JOIN
                                    users
                            ON
                                    users.user_id = groupreluser.user_id
                            WHERE 
                                    groups.group_id = '$sel'

                    ";

                    $res = $conn->query($sql);

                    if($res->num_rows > 0){

                            while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){

                                    echo $row['phone'] . '</br>';

                            }

                    }
            }
    }
}
```

It works fine as long as I dont use the checkboxes but adds the *group_id* manually in the SELECT statement. Any idea of why this isn't working? Am I missing someting? Dont know if this is the best way to do it though...
Let me know if this is unclear, and I'll try to explain it better

Comment: Is `echo '<input type="checkbox" name="checked[]"...` inside form tags? If not, PHP should be throwing you an error about it, as in "undefined index...".

Comment: can you do us a favor and var_dump several versions of $sql so we can see how messed up it is?

Comment: Sorry, didnt put that in.. yes the checkbox are inside a form tag. I have added it now to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$_POST['submit']` is array so directly passing it to `mysqli_real_escape_string`  won't work. But this approach will do the work:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$check = $_POST['check'];
if(!empty($check)){

        foreach($check as $sel) {
        $sel = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $sel);

        $sql = "

                        SELECT
                                groups.group_id,
                                groups.groupname,
                                groupreluser.user_id,
                                groupreluser.group_id,
                                users.user_id,
                                users.name,
                                users.phone
                        FROM
                                groupreluser
                        JOIN
                                groups
                        ON
                                groups.group_id = groupreluser.group_id
                        JOIN
                                users
                        ON
                                users.user_id = groupreluser.user_id
                        WHERE 
                                groups.group_id = '$sel'

                ";

                $res = $conn->query($sql);
  ...........
```

Comment: not a fan or "try this" answers, personally. Care to share why they should "try" that? maybe they'll "learn" from their mistake. ;-)

Comment: No, sorry that didnt work. I'm not getting any errors, but it just wont echo out any data

Comment: Yea, that's what I tried. I've edited the post now so you can see

Comment: What is the output if you add `print $sel;` after `$sel = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $sel);`?

Comment: Sorry @krasipenkov, I f*d up. Your version worked perfectly! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

This line probably doesn't work:
`$check = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['checked']);`

`$_POST['checked']` is an array. So you have do the line above for each item in the array.